# Question about listening

Tags: listening

Here is VOA English, I can not hear clearly of one sentence at 2:11. The script is "I'm like how it looks because it looks like most snow fall on the berries. ", but I heard is " I am like how it looks, looks like most snow fall on the berries.

could anyone help me to listen this sentence at 2:11?

http://www.kekenet.com/broadcast/202005/610691_2.shtml

Comment: The website is awkward to use (from my location at least). Many of the scripts are not exact copies and some are outright incorrect in their word choice, replacing the spoken word with a near-homophone in the script. The particular instance you ask about, your interpretation is the same as mine. (Native English speaker, UK based).

Comment: Thank you:-), Bitter